# "You are all {so/such} wonderful friends." Which is more correct?

Tags: meaning, grammar, word-choice, syntactic-analysis

In a kangarou English exam, one of the questions asked you to fill in a blank space in a sentence:

> You are all ......... wonderful friends

What is more correct to use to fill in the blank space, "so" or "such"?
According to the Cambridge Dictionary web page "*[Such](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/such-or-so)* or *so*?", from *English Grammar Today*, *so* is used when it is followed by an adjective and *such* is used when it is followed by a noun phrase.

The word *wonderful*, which follows the blank space, is an adjective, so I presume that the grammatically correct answer is *so*. However, my intuition is telling me otherwise.

In the above context, which is more correct, *so* or *such*?

Furthermore, can you please explain to me why the particular one is correct, as I believe that such a grammatical rule will help many people avoid syntax errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> so is used, when it is followed by an adjective and such is used when it is followed, by a noun phrase.

That sounds about right. Although it would be more accurate to say "modifies" or "applies to" rather than "is followed by". A word can apply that an entire phrase, not just the immediately following word. For instance, they give the example "She is such a great cook." "such" modifies the entire noun phrase "a great cook", not just the word "a".

So using "so" would force the following parsing: "you are (so wonderful) friends". That is, "so" modifies the adjective "wonderful", and the phrase "so wonderful", as a whole, modifies "friends". "such", on the other hand, would force the parsing "you are such (wonderful friends)". That is, "wonderful" modifies "friends", and then those two words together make up a noun phrase, and that entire noun phrase is modified by "such".

I find the latter more idiomatic.

Comment: Can you please tell me one last thing

Comment: is there any way that I could justify the use of so in the above context?

Comment: @kenith It certainly would be perfectly valid to say "You friends are so wonderful". Saying "You are so-wonderful friends" would be a different way to phrase that, but it would be a bit awkward.

Comment: "So" as an intensive is quite common these days; perhaps popularised by the sitcom Friends. But some people dislike it.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's 'such'

You are all such wonderful friends

I would only use 'so' in this context:

You are all so wonderful